# Cucumbers with Jenkins and vncserver throws random Timeout execution expired errors

Tags: jenkins, cucumber, vnc-server

I am new to Jenkins and have set it up with 4 slaves and trying to run Cucumbers (Capybara+Selenium+Firefox) in vncserver(tried xvfb as well) mode. But some of the slave nodes timeout randomly throwing "execution expired (Timeout::Error)" at the line below

Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1600, 900)

and in

page.driver.browser.save_screenshot(screenshot_path)

Starting from here all the remaining tests fail. Have tried using the Xvnc plugin in Jenkins as well but still fails. How do I fix this? Should I use a window manager? Will tightvnc use any default Window Manager? Is it related?

My ~/.vnc/xstartup

#!/bin/sh

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources

xsetroot -solid grey

#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &

#x-window-manager &

# Fix to make GNOME work

export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1

/etc/X11/Xsession

Does someone know what is causing the timeout error?

Comment: You also might run Firefox headless using the `geckodriver`. See an example here https://github.com/mdn/headless-examples/blob/master/headlessfirefox-gradle/src/main/java/com/mozilla/example/HeadlessFirefoxSeleniumExample.java

Comment: Yeah. That's what I have decided to do if I can't find a solution for this. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this happened because it took time for the browser to open at times so we have to wait or assert till the browser loads. Link here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15345/selenium-webdriver-sometimes-fails-to-connect-to-the-browser-when-running-tests